# Can't create simple CakePHP plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.x

I would like to create a plugin for CakePHP 3.1.4. The documentation is straight forward, but the example doesn't work (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins)

The steps are:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app sampleapp
```

Create the database. Connect to the database. Create a table "contacts". Navigate in the directory and run:

```
bin/cake bake plugin ContactManager
```

Create the controller:

```
bin/cake bake controller --plugin ContactManager Contacts
```

Re-generate the autoloader:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Add this line to the /config/bootstrap.php file:

```
Plugin::load('ContactManager', ['routes' => true]);
```

But now, the documentation sais

> "If you want to access what we’ve got going thus far, visit
>   /contact-manager/contacts. You should get a “Missing Model” error
>   because we don’t have a Contact model defined yet."

But this doesn't work. Instead I get an error:

> Missing Controller. 
>   Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException.
>   Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
>   Error: ContactManagerController could not be found.  Error: Create the
>   class ContactManagerController below in file:
>   src/Controller/ContactManagerController.php

This means the plugin could not be loaded otherwise it would not suggest this. When opening the DebugKit under "Include" the plugin is not in the plugins array.

I checked the composer.json files and in both the plugin is listed correctly. The bake command ran through without errors. I tried the above steps with multiple new projects with different names.

What is the problem here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you create the `plugins/ContactManager/config/routes.php` file like the tutorial says?

Comment: @ADmad The bake command for the plugin creates this file already and the contents of the file match the documentation. I just gave it another try.

Comment: When adding manual routing in /plugins/ContactManager/config/routes.php it seams to work and show the correct template page.  

`Router::connect('/contactmanager/contacts/view/*',['plugin' => 'ContactManager', 'controller' => 'Contacts', 'action' => 'view']);`  

But this should work without adding every route for every action manually, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

What the docs say should be in `/plugins/ContactManager/config/routes.php` AND what `bake plugin` creates:

```
Router::plugin('ContactManager', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

But what really needs to be in the file instead of the above snippet is:

```
Router::scope('/contactmanager', ['plugin' => 'ContactManager'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks();
});
```

Comment: If you are sure that it is wrong in the docs as well as in the bake result I suggest to report it as issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues), so you can help to improve the open source framework :-)

Comment: Above not working for me I found another solution.

`Router::plugin('ContactManager', ['path' => '/ContactManager'], function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    });`